# SSIS dynamic connection to the source and destination.

Tags: sql-server, excel, dynamic, ssis, connection

Hi I want to create 1 SSIS packge that load excel file into a customer DB.

I have 100 customers db's  and I also have evrey new week 100 excel files 
(All the DB's and files have the same structure) the db's name is the CustomerName and the excel file name is CustomerName_date.

I want to create job that will run once a week with ssis packge that will load all the excel files in the folder to the customer db's and will transfer the file to archive folder.

what is best why to that with dynamic connection to the source and to the destination.

Comment: Why do you have 100 different Customer Dbs?  Just curious

Comment: Each customer have his own db's in my server with diffrent Proc and views and keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task can be done using variables and expressions.
The most difficult part will be to create working Connection String for OLE DB connection.

1) For processing each file in a folder, use Foreach loop.

- In loop edit window in *Collection tab*, select **"Foreach File Enumerator"**
- Select your folder, filter out Excel files (if needed) using wildcart and choose **Fully qualified name**
- Create variable for storing file path and in tab *Variable Mappings* select this variable. (In each loop, new file path will be saved in this variable).

2) Create new *Excel file connection* based on one of your excel files, right-click it and in Expressions, create Expression for connection string. In expression editor, set it to use yout file variable.

3) Then we will need to create connection string for **OLE DB** connection.

- Create new variable to holt it.
- Create *OLE DB connection* and connect it to any of your databases.
- Then right-click your connection and backup the conection string somewhere else, so you can use it in future.

4) In foreach loop, create Script task.

- In Script task editor, choose *ReadOnlyVariables* (your file name) and *ReadWriteVariables* (your prepared connection string)
- Click **Edit script** and in new VisualStudio Window, create your script.
- Variables can be read and written to like this:

  string myValue = (string)Dts.Variables["User::"].Value;
- You can parse the excel name from fileName variable and create new connection string for OLE DB to match the previously saved one.

5) Edit your OLE DB connection Expressions and match Connection String to the variable.

6) In the foreach loop, create **Data Flow Task** and double-click it. Use **Excel source** and make it use your Excel connection. Then create **OLE DB destination** and make it use your OLE DB connection.

---

Use this Answer as a suggestion, maybe it will need soma playing around before it will work. But based on my experience, this approach should work.